# MVC4 Ajax Request

Tags: jquery

This is my Controller class

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ContactUs()
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_ContactUs");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

My problem return PartialView("_ContactUs");
is not getting executing in MVC4 directly  return View();
 is getting executed

Comment: What is the javascript code you are using to call this action

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an action method selector to differentiate between Ajax and non-Ajax requests. So, implement ActionMethodSelectorAttribute and decorate your action method with that attribute (true). See sample code below.

```
[HttpGet]
[MyAjax(true)]
public ActionResult ContactUs()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView("_ContactUs");
    }

    return View();
}

//.. 

public class MyAjaxAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
    {
        private readonly bool _ajax;
        public AjaxAttribute(bool ajax)
        {
            _ajax = ajax;
        }

        // Determines whether the action method selection is valid for the specified controller context
        public override bool IsValidForRequest(
                               ControllerContext controllerContext,
                               MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            return _ajax == controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
        }
    }
```